# SOAP end point mocking with XML files

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I've to develop some functionality to client side of web service using SOAP. I'm using jaxws-maven-plugin to generate client side class files and  I'd like to use raw xml-files to simulate the end point response when testing. Is this possible to do without some external tools like SoapUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Set up an Endpoint during unit-testing and mock using for example Mockito. I've put up a simple JUnit Rule project which does this: [mockito-soap-cxf](https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be exactly what I was looking for!